# Create array with function javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need to create function that creates and returns array. Its size needs to match the rows parameter, and each next element contains consecutive integers starting at 1. To call this function I need to use argument 5. Here below is what I wrote so far. Can you tell me what's wrong here?

```
function createArray(rows) {
    for(let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
        console.log(rows[i]);
    }return rows;
}
createArray(5);
```

Comment: Rows is initially used as the integer to now how many rows.  But then you check it's length like it's an array.  You need to define an array inside the function, then add i to it in each iteration of the loop.  Then return that array.  In your for loop definition, just compare `i < row` rather than `i < row.length`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array and return it, whereas you return just `rows` which is a number. The idea of using a for loop is the best way to go. In that loop you just need to set the values in the array accordinlgy.
Another problem in your code is that `rows` is of type number and does have a property length but that does not have the desired value. So we just use `rows` in the for loop. We start the loop with `i = 0` because array indices start at 0.

### Code

```js
function createArray(rows) {
  let arr = new Array(rows);
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    arr[i] = i + 1;
  }
  
  return arr;
}

console.log(createArray(5));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is createArray(5) return [1,2,3,4,5] if that's the case you could do this

```js
function createArray(rows) {
    const arr = []
    for(let i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(createArray(5));
```

Comment: Very good solution to use the literal syntax instead of the constructor one. But you stated in your introduction that the function should return `[1,2,3,4,5]`, which it does not. So your solution is one off.

Answer (score 0):

We can not use length property for number. create an empty array and then push values into that array until required size is achieved.

```
function createArray(rows) {
    var arr = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        arr.push(i);
    }return arr;
}
createArray(5);
```

Answer (score -2):

The problem is, that rows.length is not available on `5`, because `5` is a number.

You have to use an array as parameter:

`Array(5)` creates an array with the length of 5 and `fill("hello")` fills this array with "hello" values.

```js
function createArray(rows) {
  for (let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    console.log(rows[i]);
  }
  return rows;
}

const rows = Array(5).fill("hello");

createArray(rows);
```

I don't know, if this is the behaviour you want, if not, I misunderstood your question.